# foreach loop with PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, Invalid argument supplied

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I'm quering my database, and want to write a foreach loop, that goes trough my result set, and runs `strtotime` on the timestamp, in order to use it on my webpage (I want to adjust the array["posted"] value to strtotime(array["posted"]).

I am new to php and PDO, and can't figure out what's wrong with my foreach loop. The warning I get is `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/shooshte/Dropbox/PTC_php/db_queries/articles.php on line 29` .

I guess I'm targeting the `$result` array wrong? Can anyone explain how to fix this? The timestamp is in the column called `posted`, which is also the key inside my array.

Thanks for the help.

my php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

try {
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=topdecka_PTC",$username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if (!empty($_POST["searchword"])) {
        $searchword = $_POST["searchword"];
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT title, posted, author_id, extract FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :searchword OR extract LIKE :searchword OR body LIKE :searchword");      
        $query->execute(array(":searchword" => "%" . $searchword . "%"));
        $result = $query->fetchAll();

        echo json_encode($result);
        die();
    } 
    else {
        $query = $db->prepare('SELECT posted FROM articles');
        $query->execute();

        $result = $query->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row) {
            $row['posted'] = strtotime($row['posted']);
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);
        echo '</pre>';

        //echo json_encode($result);
        die();
    }
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

Here's the `var_dump`:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["posted"]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-10 11:16:46"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-10 11:16:46"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["posted"]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-10 13:26:54"
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-10 13:26:54"
  }
}
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($result);` display?

Comment: @honerlawd added var_dump to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is occuring on line 29 (so at `foreach($row['posted'] as $time)`). The reason is that `$row['posted']` is not an array.

Change the loop to this

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($result); ++$i) {
  $result[$i]['posted'] = strtotime($result[$i]['posted']) * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried `foreach($result as $row) {
   $row['posted'] = strtotime($row['posted']);
  }` , as I want to change the actual value before encoding it and printing it on, but nothing happens (the var_dump still shows `["posted"]=>
    string(19) "2015-06-10 11:16:46"`)

Comment: oh you want to reset the value of `$row['posted']`?

Comment: yeh, I want to set it to strtotime * 1000, so I can format it using jQuery =)

Comment: yeh, got it working. thanks a lot, now I can move on to JS =)

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič Interesting question, but it would have saved the good people, a lot of time if you had posted your intentions and what the ultimate goal was in your question immediately upon posting your question. ;-)

Comment: @ Fred -ii- I thought that "I'm quering my database, and want to write a foreach loop, that goes trough my result set, and runs `strtotime` on the timestamp, in order to use it on my webpage" made it clear enough. Edited the post to make it clearer for future references

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this will work but i think i did something like this when i had this problem.

```
$resultset = array();
   while ($row = $query->fetch()) { $resultset[] = $row; }  

   foreach($resultset as $result) {
        foreach($row["posted"] as $time) {
            $time = strtotime($time);
        }   
    }
```